# How can I publish my ASP.Net Core Angular web app to Azure without using git in Visual Studio Code

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, angular7

Having a ASP.Net Core/Angular app I know I can publish to Azure using git like in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb?toc=%2Faspnet%2Fcore%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Faspnet%2Fcore%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=aspnetcore-2.2#deploy-app-to-azure) on the ASP.Net Core page in Visual Studio Code

But I can't find any tutorial or directions on how to publish my web app directly to Azure from the cli.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: check out this blog post https://medium.com/@omikolaj1/complete-guide-to-deploying-angular-and-asp-net-33a0976d0ec1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this cli (az webapp deployment source ) to publish to Azure web app. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/cli-deploy-staging-environment

Comment: Hi looking at the link I see it sets up everything (resource group, app service, etc) I have all that, I just need to publish from VS Code to my web app in Azure. Also what is the purpose of the slot? I know I can publish without a slot, so why is it needed?

Comment: Additionally is there a way to publish to Azure from VS Code without having to use az cli?

Comment: You can use the Azure App Service extension for Visual Studio Code to publish from VS code.  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vscode?view=aspnetcore-2.2.
The slot is used for staging and test. For example, you can first publish to a stage slot, and if there is no problem, then you can swap two slots (usually from a staging slot into the production slot). For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots

Comment: Hi Farid. Thanks for the explanation. Do you know best practices for creating a second db for testing/staging? So if I push to a staging/testing slot I can use a staging/testing db!